# Django Admin: Register multiple admin classes to the same model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Is it possible to register multiple admin classes to the same model? I want to have both PostAdmin and MyPostAdmin register to the Post model. Right now I'm trying to use a proxy model with MyPost, but it's giving me two different models in the admin panel with their separate functionality.

admin.py:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('title',)}

class MyPostAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    summernote_fields = ('text', )

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
admin.site.register(MyPost, MyPostAdmin)
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=category_choices, default=0)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_URL)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class MyPost(Post):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't need to make a proxy model. I fixed the issue by adding the prepopulated_fields variable to the MyPostAdmin class

Comment: Can you share more specific details of your answer?

Comment: Good suggestion fixed my problem too. I wanted one model with auto-generated on save hidden slug field and another that could edit the slug if desired. `prepopulated_fields` will add some javascript that automatically calculates the `slug` value as the `title` is being typed. The rest can be handled via user training. Unfortunately does not account for duplicates if your slug is set as `unique=True`

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case of `SummernoteModelAdmin`, you can use multiple inhertance for creating a single admin class instead of using PRoxy Models:

```
class MyPostAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    summernote_fields = ('text', )
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('title',)}

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```