# Registering multiple admin classes with a model in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've two Admin classes for a single model:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin
from .models import *

class ProductSummernoteAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    summernote_fields = ('description',)

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

admin.site.register(Product, ProductSummernoteAdmin)
```

I want to register both `ProductSummernoteAdmin` and `ProductAdmin` with `Product` model. How to do that? As, i can't register same model twice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple ModelAdmins/views for same model in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223375/multiple-modeladmins-views-for-same-model-in-django-admin)

Comment: That is using Proxy models. Is there any way without that? I read this one one, but the answer is too vague: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54209583/django-admin-register-multiple-admin-classes-to-the-same-model

Comment: Then the answer is a big No, You can't do that

Comment: Well, I found a bypass using multiple inheritance. Gonna add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a quick bypass for registering both `SummernoteModelAdmin` and `admin.ModelAdmin` classes using **multiple inheritance** without Proxy Models:

```
class ProductAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    summernote_fields = ('description',)

    class Meta:
        model = Product

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```